# Spotify Login With Mail and Password python

Tags: python, authentication, spotify, bearer-token

I want to log in to my spotify account and get my bearer token.I tried to do this with the requests module, but I couldn't manage the login operations.I would be very happy if you tell me how to log in to the account with the requests module and get the bearer token.If you don't know this, I would be very happy if you could log in to the account with the selenium module and tell me how to get the value in the image below :) (logins to the account are by mail, password)

[image: bearer token value]

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to get your bearer token?, Try to web scrape it by using the BeautifulSoup and the requests library. Or you can also use a spotify API, like spotipy
https://github.com/plamere/spotipy

but i would rather recommend you using API, because web scraping can be difficult.

Comment: yes i want to get bearer token but i don't know where it is located. i think it is same for every website

Comment: At the same time, I want to login to the account with a password, not a client key.

Comment: @EmrovskyEmrovsky The bearer token is probably located in the Back-End, so it is not scrapeable. But i would still recommend you doing some Google/YouTube search. And for the auto login, i would recommend using the Selenium library.